# cakephp 3.x datetime field comparison in query not returning correct result

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

Trying to get all the records with which has been created 24 hr or prior. Here 'created' is a datatime field. I've three records in DB which must satisfy this condition, but returning 0 records.

```
$my_table_tbl = TableRegistry::get('my_table');
$records = $my_table_tbl
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'created <' => '(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)',
        'status' => 'pending'
    ])
    ->toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP will always treat the right side of a clause as a variable binding. That means `(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)` is interpreted as a string value.

You can check what SQL is generated by converting the query to a string.

```
$query = $my_table_tbl->find()
              ->where([
                 'created <' => '(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)',
                 'status' => 'pending'
              ]);
dd((string)$query);
```

When you output the SQL above it will show `created < :c0` instead of your expression.

Use a query object to create a custom expressions.

```
$q = $my_table_tbl->query();
$query = $my_table_tbl
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'created <' => $q->newExp('(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)'),
        'status' => 'pending'
    ]);
dd((string)$query);
```

When you output the SQL above it will show `created < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)` as expected. This is because CakePHP checks if the values on the right hand are an expression object.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, there's also [**`FunctionsBuilder::dateAdd()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Database.FunctionsBuilder.html#_dateAdd) which supports generating cross-schema compatible SQL.

Comment: @cgtag It worked for me, many thanks. **newExpr()** - method for creating Row Expression did the magic.